# How to use embedded ruby in ActionMailer subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I'm trying to use some embedded ruby in the subject line of an email coming from ActionMailer but keep getting different errors.

I couldn't find any documentation on the proper syntax. Any resources to fix this line of code?

```
mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Your Reservation Confirmation for" + @restaurant.name)
```

I've passed in all of the variables fine. I just need to see how I can combine text and these inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of a specific attempt and the specific error message you get.

Comment: The mail line before is what is generating the error. It works with if I just have the portion in "quotes" and no embedded ruby. But it gives me a "TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String" I guess it thinks I'm trying to do math instead of concatenate

Comment: Hmm, sounds like `@restaurant.name` is returning a number for some reason. What happens if you change it to `"...Confirmation for" + @restaurant.name.to_s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is intentional, but apparently `@restaurant.name` is returning a number (as you clarified, you're getting a `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`). Calling `@restaurant.name.to_s` will solve that.

[As G.B mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23882628/1426950), string interpolation like "...Confirmation for #{@restaurant.name}" works too, since it calls `#to_s` for you automatically.

I'm putting the solution into an answer, since we found it while clarifying in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways to it:

First:(regarding rep)

```
"...Confirmation for" + @restaurant.name.to_s
```

Second:
you can use string interpolation

```
"...Confirmation for #{@restaurant.name}"
```